# How to apply Serilog for asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, serilog

Goal:
Use Serilog for asp.net core mvc and then retrieve log data in a txt file.

Problem:
The code doesn't work. What part of the code am I missing?

Info:
*Using .net 5
*Code from this page (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) works in relation to console but not for asp.net core mvc

Thank you!

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("You are here!");


            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a sample code to setup serilog in Asp.core 3.1 MVC at https://github.com/pramireddy/Lab.Setup.Serilog.AspMVc

Answer (score 1):

We had to add serilog to the `Program.cs` file:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config.Build()).CreateLogger();
                })
                .UseSerilog()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: To clarify a bit more,  by using UseSerilog, you make sure the logging framework of .NET Core is passing logging to Serilog too.

Comment: Exactly where should the code 'CreateWebHostBuilder' should be applied in asp.net core mvc solution?